# Display nested records on UI wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, entity-framework

I have used Entity Framework to develop a WPF application with SQL Server as backend database. I want to query the database and show the results in excel file

I have a Parent Table called TestPack that has around 25 fields. Each TestPack may have many InternalWalks, ExternalWalks, Flushings, Spools etc.

Now I want to run a query like this "Return all TestPacks that have InternalWalks or Flushings".

The testPacks returned should have InternalWalk and Flushing data as well and it needs to be displayed in a grid.

Here is my query

```
Project.GetAllTestPacks().Where(t => t.InternalWalks.Count != 0 || t.Flushings.Count != 0 ).ToList();
```

This query does return me the results that I want i.e Only those test packs are returned that have Flushings or Internalwalks and relevant Flushings and InternalWalks data is fetched as well through lazyloading. Now I want to display this data on UI and also want to export this to excel. How do I do that?

Comment: You should avoid to ask a question two or more times. If you want to add more details just edit your first question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display result from One to Many relationship table in WPF UI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241535/display-result-from-one-to-many-relationship-table-in-wpf-ui)